# Need to find the file name where the SQL error occurs for an AWS Lambda copying data from S3 to Snowflake

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am copying data from S3 file into Snowflake.
I am testing this by trying to push "bad" data into snowflake so push a varchar into a timestamp column.
This is the JSON:

```
 {
    object: "account",
    event: "userRegistered",
    data: {
      accountId: "52cc5f80-9556-40a8-b645-96d01200f831",
      accountNumber: "a8j3edqxl1k",
      firstName: "Ariel",
      lastName: "Cummings",
      email: "Ariel.Cummings809kr5348aj72@e3bmogriim8.ocn3oysypzo.org",
      mobileNumber: "977331296705",
      terms_version: "v4",
      marketingFlags: false,
      marketingChannels: "Text",
      marketingTypes: "Promo",
      provider: "Google"
    },
    eventId: "5089c4a0-d54b-4919-a4b3-348154ff57ce",
    timestamp: "foobarla",
    context: "faker"
  }];
```

And this is the SQL script I run

```
COPY INTO accounts(timestamp, context, object, event, event_id,
                              schema_version, data, filename, file_row_number) 
                  FROM (SELECT   CAST(parse_json($1):timestamp AS timestamp), 
                                 parse_json($1):context, 
                                 parse_json($1):object, 
                                 parse_json($1):event, 
                                 parse_json($1):event_id, 
                                 null,
                                 parse_json($1):data, 
                                 metadata$filename, 
                                 metadata$file_row_number 
                        FROM @DEV_UNWRAPT_ACCOUNTS_STAGE(file_format => JSON))  
                        pattern='.*dev-unwrapt-data-account.*'
                        on_error = 'skip_file';
```

When I do this I receive an error object from Snowflake that I am console.logging.

The error object that returns is:

```
error { OperationFailedError: Failed to cast variant value "foobarla" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ
    at createError (C:\Users\206580214\WebstormProjects\unwrapt-analytics-snowflake\terraform\lambda_src\snowflakeImport\node_modules\snowflake-sdk\lib\errors.js:474:15)
    at Object.exports.createOperationFailedError (C:\Users\206580214\WebstormProjects\unwrapt-analytics-snowflake\terraform\lambda_src\snowflakeImport\node_modules\snowflake-sdk\lib\errors.
js:282:10)
    at Object.callback (C:\Users\206580214\WebstormProjects\unwrapt-analytics-snowflake\terraform\lambda_src\snowflakeImport\node_modules\snowflake-sdk\lib\services\sf.js:525:26)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\206580214\WebstormProjects\unwrapt-analytics-snowflake\terraform\lambda_src\snowflakeImport\node_modules\snowflake-sdk\lib\http\base.js:104:21)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\206580214\WebstormProjects\unwrapt-analytics-snowflake\terraform\lambda_src\snowflakeImport\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\206580214\WebstormProjects\unwrapt-analytics-snowflake\terraform\lambda_src\snowflakeImport\node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\206580214\WebstormProjects\unwrapt-analytics-snowflake\terraform\lambda_src\snowflakeImport\node_modules\request\request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
  name: 'OperationFailedError',
  code: '100071',
  message: 'Failed to cast variant value "foobarla" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ',
  sqlState: '22000',
  data:
   { internalError: false,
     errorCode: '100071',
     age: 0,
     sqlState: '22000',
     queryId: 'ae3b88e1-7cb1-42de-b66d-9fd987c958d3' } }
```

Is there any way of finding out the file name in S3 where this error occurs from this object or another route?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`VALIDATION_MODE` option](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#validating-staged-files) of the COPY syntax to go through the files and report errors.

Alternatively, you can also use the [`VALIDATE`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/validate.html) command to test what happened in the previously ran `COPY` statement.

Comment: When I add this to the copy command "validation_mode = 'RETURN_ERRORS';"  I get the following error:

"SQL Compilation error: Expression 'TIMESTAMP' not supported within a VALIDATE expression.

Comment: When i use VALIDATE e.g. select * from table(validate(accounts, job_id => 'd2c2dee5-816b-4c1f-b890-e05abfbbb59d'))
I get the following error:
SQL compilation error: JSON/XML/AVRO file format can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array. Use CSV file format if you want to load more than one column.

Comment: You are using copy transformation with JSON file format, which Snowflake currently doesn't support advanced error handling. We are making improvement in this area and you should be able to see which file an error is from after a couple of weeks.